# automatic creation of the program schema

Tags: java, diagram

Are there any ways to automatically create a program schema (specifically interested in Java/IDEA)? I mean schema wich shows what classes and methods exist, what from where is called, what parameters are passed, etc. This would greatly simplify the understanding of the project structure.
Maybe there is some plugin for IDEA?

PS
I can create such a schema in MS Visio manually, but it takes much time, so I would like to do it automatically.

Comment: Did you look at [DoxyGen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)? It can give you that - even from code with zero DoxyGen comments.

Comment: Also, take a look at a few of [these](https://alternativeto.net/software/understand/?license=free). Please, let us know if any help you. Good luck